# Have you ever applied to enter or remain in Canada? Does being in the express entry pool for Canada count as an application?

Tags: visas, canada, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas

I am about to apply for a visitor Visa to Canada, I am in the pool for express entry so I am not sure if that qualifies as a formal  application.

Has anyone in the pool said no to this question and been granted a visa before? Do visa officers have access to all express entry applicants in the pool even though they have not made a formal PR application?

Comment: Have you gone are far as submitting your profile? If so, I would think that, yes, as any immigration requests (live, study, work, visit, transit) are within an individual's record.

Comment: I don't think being in the pool counts, because you have not yet actually made your application to remain in Canada.

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify.  PUtting on hold for now.